# Alter url suggestions list with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to influence the suggestions offered in address bar of browser? For example, I would like to capture user's input and display my own list of suggestions.

Comment: As an individual user or for an enterprise use case?

Comment: [Chrome extension modify suggest and search urls](//stackoverflow.com/q/39147153)

Comment: @AG1 what do you mean?

Comment: @wOxxOm Disagree with the duplicate; generally, I don't think this question is specific enough. Goehybrid, please edit the question to explain in an example (or multiple examples) what kind of "influence" you are looking for.

Comment: @Xan I've included an example to the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's not specific enough. Can you explain _step-by-step_ a scenario you want to have?

Comment: @xan let's say I have a list of articles. Whenever user types something into the search bar, instead of showing the suggested drop list of links, I would like to capture user's input, search through my list of articles, find those with a title matching user's input and then show those articles in the drop list instead.

Comment: There's an API for providing suggestions, but the user would need to input a keyword first: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox